# How to generate client api from different module

Tags: java, maven, swagger, microservices, swagger-codegen

I'm building 2 microservices. One named **cart**, and second one named **product**. Both of them have API generated via `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`, however now I want that **cart** microservice will have generated client api from yaml file deffinition which resides in product module (the one from which product have generated server client). How can I achive that? Is there a way to access yaml file from different module? What kind of dependency I have to have?

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-cart-server</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <configOptions>
                            <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[image: Project structure]

Comment: As you are in the same project, you can use relative paths to access files in other modules. `${project.basedir}../product/src/main/resources/static/api.yaml` will do the trick. Plus, of course, correctly configuring the plugin to generate the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative paths as long as you are inside the same project. You have to add multiple `execution` tags to generate both, client for product and server for cart.

```xml
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-cart-server</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/api.yaml</inputSpec>
            <language>spring</language>
            <configOptions>
                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
            </configOptions>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-product-client</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../product/src/main/resources/static/api.yaml</inputSpec>
            <language>java</language>
            <library>resttemplate</library>
            <configOptions>
                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
            </configOptions>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Use `<language>java</language>` to generate Java client code and choose a library you'd like to use with `<library>...</library>`. RestTemplate is a part of Spring, but there are many others.

Quoting from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen#2-generate-client):

```
 Swagger Codegen supports the following Java libraries (pairs of HTTP 
clients and JSON processing libraries):

    jersey1 – Jersey1 + Jackson
    jersey2 – Jersey2 + Jackson
    feign – OpenFeign + Jackson
    okhttp-gson – OkHttp + Gson
    retrofit (Obsolete) – Retrofit1/OkHttp + Gson
    retrofit2 – Retrofit2/OkHttp + Gson
    resttemplate – Spring RestTemplate + Jackson
    rest-easy – Resteasy + Jackson
```

Of course, you need to add the selected library to your dependencies as well.

Comment: The reading of path worked as a charm, as you suggested, but still plugin generates for me Server API not Client API, is there some kind of property I have to add ?

Comment: I'm following point 5. from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen with no results. Additionaly maven tells me to remove <library>resttemplate</library> property

Comment: Do I need any kind of additional dependencies? Execution generate-product-client of goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.4.0:generate failed: Unknown library: resttemplate. Avalable libraries: spring-boot, spring-mvn, spring-cloud.

Comment: Although I can use RestTemplate class in my project

Comment: It worked, I had to changed language to JAVA and than set library to resttemplate. Also spring-web dependency was needed. I'm marking this question as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, good, I was wondering why this didn't work. So now you have `<language>java</language>` and `<library>resttemplate</resttemplate>`, right?

Comment: Yes, if language is set to spring, you are not able to select "resettemplate" in library property